# PHP print array inside JSON

Tags: php, arrays, json

I need this type of json response in PHP

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Something went wrong!"
    }
  ]
}
```

Where "errors" is an array, and "message" is encoded in json

If I encode it something like this

```
json_encode (['errors' => ['message' => 'Unauthenticated.']])
```

it prints like

```
{
  "errors": {
    "message": "Unauthenticated."
  }
}
```

but I want it like above, any proper solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
json_encode(['errors' => [['message' => 'Unauthenticated.']]]);
```

output:

```
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "message": "Unauthenticated."
        }
    ]
}
```